# Can anyone explain what es7 reflect-metadata is all about?

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, jspm, systemjs, ecmascript-2016

Been studying ES6, JSPM & angular2 for a week now and I found this repo [ES6-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata)

if we look at the index.html at the bottom script you'll see

```
 System.import('reflect-metadata')
  .then(function() {
    return System.import('app/index');
  })
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

This is using JSPM's systemjs polyfill to get ES6's `import`.

**Question:**  What is the reflect-metadata really do in this situation? [npm reflect-meta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) The more I read the documentation, the less I understand what it does?

Comment: Not sure what index.html you mean, if it's the https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/index.html, then the reflect-metadata/Reflect.js  is a library which enhances: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect which is being used sometimes in the code which the TypeScript compiler (tsc) spits out

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`'reflect-metadata'`  is a package that is a proposal for ES7.  It allow for meta data to be included to a class or function; essentially it is [syntax sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Example.
Angular 2 ES6:

```
@Component({selector: "thingy"})
@View({template: "<div><h1>Hello everyone</h1></div>"})
class Thingy{};
```

As you can see there are no semicolons after @Component and @View.  This is because they are essentially Chains of (meta)data on the class.

Now lets look at that same code in Angular 2 but in ES5:

```
function Thingy(){}
Thingy.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: "thingy"
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({

        template: "<div><h1>Hello everyone</h1></div>"
    })
];
```

As you can see the @ symbol abstracts out alot of the annotations property of a class and makes it More [D.R.Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Taking this one step further Angular team knows that annotations are a bit abstract for the new user.  Moreover, the ES5 is just too verbose.  which is why they made `a.js` which will make interfacing with annotations better:

[Video to understand this](https://youtu.be/YhcOeJP06Zc?t=1265)

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Comment: What is a.js?  My comment is not long enough

Comment: @gyozokudor a.js was a project for angular 2 and es5.  It seems asif angular 2 team may have discontinued this project.